# How to pass the string value to function

Tags: vb6

I want to pass the string value to function

Function Code

```
Private Function Assign(Div As String)

        sSQL = "Insert into table2 Select * from table1 Where Divi_Code = '" & Div & "'"
        Rdoconn.Execute sSQL, rdExecDirect

End Function
```

Button Click Code

```
Dim Div as string
Div = "Hai,Howareyou"
Assign Div  'Getting Error as "ByRef arguement type mismatch"
```

The above code is shwoing error as Getting Error as `"ByRef arguement type mismatch"`

Comment: If you comment out the lines inside your Assign function, does it still throw an error?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste your real code rather than retyping? This can hide errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the following code, and I am not getting any ByRef argument mismatch.

```
Private Function Assign(Div As String)
    ssql = "Insert into table2 Select * from table1 Where Divi_Code = '" & Div & "'"
    MsgBox ssql
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim Div As String
    Div = "Hai,Howareyou"
    Assign Div
End Sub
```

I am really puzzled why your code is giving you an error. However, there are a couple of things you should change in your code and I'm confident this will resolve your problem:

- The function parameter should be declared ByVal. In VB6, parameters are ByRef by default unless specified. This means that the function call could have side-effects in the parent procedure if for any reason the parameter Div is modified. **Always** use ByVal unless you really need to modify the parameter value:

  Private Function Assign(ByVal Div As String)
- Is there any reason why you declared Assign as a Function? Are you intending to return a value? If not, you should use Private Sub instead of Private Function (and End Sub at the end). This is equivalent to using the void return type in C. For your reference, you should always define the return type of your functions in VB6, otherwise Variant will be assumed. The return type can be fined in functions using the "As" keyword at the end of the declaration:

  Private Function Add(ByVal n1 as Integer, ByVal n2 As Integer) As Integer

One last thing I'd like to add is that you never, ever should concatenate variables to SQL queries like this. At the very least, the code will crash if the name contains an apostrophe (ex: try calling it with "I'm very well"), and at worst, you'll be opening up for SQL injection attacks where someone could use this to run specially crafted queries on your database. While I'm not familiar with RDO, you should check out MSDN - [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262314%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) mentions how to create parameter queries with RDO.

Answer (score 1):

To call a Function declared as

```
Private Function AssignDiv(Div As String, Dep As String)
```

you'd need something like

```
AssignDiv Div, "WhatEverDep"
```

Your

```
Assign Div
```

is completely wrong.

You changed your declaration to

```
Private Function AssignDiv(Div As String)
```

but the function's name is still wrong.

You changed your code again. Now names and parameters match, so if you still get an error, it's not caused by the code you published.

Answer (score 0):

to begin with I don't understand why you are setting you Div value and then passing it into your function, you may as well pass it in directly on the button click, and then also I can't see that sSQL is actually defined as a string, please try the following code:

```
Public Function Assign(strDiv As String)           
Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = "Insert into table2 Select * from table1 Where Divi_Code = '" & strDiv & "'"         
Rdoconn.Execute sSQL, rdExecDirect
End Function
```

And then call from the button click as:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Call Assign("Hai,Howareyou")
End Sub
```